# Eclipse flags C++ string literal as "Invalid Argument"

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

After moving all my code to a new M2 MacBook, my old Eclipse 4.17 (2020-09) now flags string literal arguments as "Invalid Argument".

I've since updated to the latest Eclipse 2023-06/AArch64", installed CDT, the PDT PHP Tools and Wild Web.

The problem with string literals in C++ remains.  I've read a ton of old posts ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008293/clean-eclipse-index-it-is-out-of-sync-with-code/3040761#3040761)) and tried rebuilding the index, freshening all files, and setting the discovery to `-std=c++11` [per this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041054/stdmove-invalid-argument-in-ecplise).

For example, given the trivial program below, the call to `test("bobo")` is flagged as an invalid argument, even though `std::string` is bridged to literal strings and the program compiles without error.

Any suggestions?

```
#include <string>

void test(const std::string &s)
{ }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string s;
    test(s);       // (1) OK
    test("bobo");  // (2) Eclipse says "Invalid Argument"
    test(12);      // (3) Eclipse says "Invalid Argument" (which is expected)
}
```

[image]

**EDIT I**

With the suggestion from [majixin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15274669/majixin) I deleted all the hidden eclipse settings files and folders.  I've tried a few things but no luck:

1. File > New Project > General > Project creates a blank project with no detection of C/C++ features.  Trying File > New > Convert to C++ Project got syntax highlighting with the same errors.
2. File > New Makefile Project with existing code:
   Same problem: lines 2 and 3 show Invalid Argument
3. File > New C/C++ Project (selecting "Makefile Project" from the popup window)

The parser log file says:

```
Unresolved names:
   Attempt to use symbol failed: test in file /Users/danny/Programming/eclipseWS/Dummy/junk.cpp:24
   Attempt to use symbol failed: test in file /Users/danny/Programming/eclipseWS/Dummy/junk.cpp:25
```

(I also tried installing GNU g++ via homebrew but looking at the indexer log file, looks like Eclipse still used clang to validate symbols.  No joy.)

Comment: This seems highly unusual. I can only suggest something in Eclipse's ```.cproject``` and/or ```.project``` file is amiss. Backup copies somewhere for your project. Then delete the originals (not backups) and re-import your project as you would normally. See if that makes any difference. If it does, it may be worth comparing the resulting ```.project``` and ```.cproject``` files with the backed-up originals to see why there could be a difference for M2 MacBooks.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling for a long time, I got it to work by:

1. Creating a new empty project
2. Converting the project to C++
3. Copying files and folders one by one into the new project
4. Adding these include paths to the "C++ Paths and Symbols" section:

   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include
   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/